# Apache internal host of repository for Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, web-server, apt

Is there a way to store .deb files on a Apache server on Ubuntu and be able to install them on a Pi with the `sudo apt-get install` command?

Comment: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?&t=23819

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Here is the answer you are looking for (done from root, or with sudo)

1. Install Apache

   ```
   apt-get install apache2
   ```
2. Create a Debian Package Repository Directory

   ```
   mkdir /var/www/debs/arm
   ```
3. Move your debs to the /var/www/debs/arm directory
4. Go to /var/www/debs directory if not already there

   ```
   cd /var/www/debs
   ```
5. Run the following command to create a packages.gz file

   ```
   dpkg-scanpackages arm | gzip -9c > arm/Packages.gz
   ```
6. Now we need to make the repository known to apt by updating /etc/apt/sources.list

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

and add line that looks like this (based off examples so far)

```
deb http://localhost/debs/
```

7. Now update APT

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
8. Now your pretty much done, the only thing left to do is try it out. I set one up as I was writing this and verified it worked.

This is how i verified. I used node to test it.

```
 wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
 sudo mv node_latest_armhf.deb /var/www/debs/arm

 cd /var/www/debs
 dpkg-scanpackages arm | gzip -9c > arm/Packages.gz
```

I then edited /etc/apt/sources.list. I commented out the default, and added my created

```
 sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

 #deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main firmware
 #deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian wheezy main
 deb `http://192.168.1.90/debs/ arm/`

 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install node
```

Just to show you it worked, but it does give a "The following packages cannot be authenticated!" warning

[image: Proof of work]

Edit: As you can see from my example and screenshot, I used my pi's IP address, rather than using local host, but you can go either way.

Also, you may consider using lighttpd or nginx instead of apache as it will use less resources.

Edit 2: Ok, in comments you stated you are getting an error

```
malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
```

So there is something wrong with line 2. I am using Raspbian Minimal (raspbian-ua-netinst), but here is my /etc/apt/sources.list. Yours will probably have more entries. The first two entries are the default, I commented them out just to test the setup as I did not want node to install from anywhere but my package repo. So take a look at line 2 and make sure it matches the format of what I posted below. There is probably an extra space on that line, no space where there needs to be one or maybe an accidental character or something along those lines. Afterwards run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

[image: apt-sources]

Comment: i have tried this and get a error on the pi saying `malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)`

Comment: I updated the answer. See Edit 2.

Comment: no it matchs what you have posted but if on firefox i got to localhost/debs/ iget page not found so shall i move it into my html folder where i put my php pages to

Comment: yes, you must have your host setup differently than the defaults, or your on a vhost. Move the debs directory to html folder.

Comment: no problem, sorry it took me so long to answer. As I stated in my original answer I didn't think could be done. I found [This](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/debianubuntu_making_package_repository_your_lan) in a google search and tested on my secondary pi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19933/discussion-between-jhondoe-and-geoffmcc).

Comment: i am now having a probale say unabale to locate package any ideas the file is called piconfig.deb and is in the /var/www/html/debs/arm/ and i have ran the scan packages

Comment: meet me in chat

Comment: i did not see your message to meet you in chat till over an  hour after you posted sorrey @geoffmcc

Comment: Did you ever get it working? Did you maybe try with a different deb. Today a hectic day for me, so probably wont be answering much today

Comment: No".............

Answer (score 4):

You can put the debs up on a server on Ubuntu, but you won't be able to install them without first using something like the following from a terminal.

```
 wget servername/name.deb
```

Then you can

```
 sudo dpkg -i name.deb
```

Another option though would be to setup Ubuntu as an NFS server and use the Pi as a client. Then you can set up `/etc/fstab` to auto mount the NFS share on the Pi. Then you would just go to wherever you mounted the share in Pi, and run the same command:

```
sudo dpkg -i name.deb
```

If the NFS idea is of interest to you, you should have no problem finding out how to do on ask, or other places. It is pretty easy to setup.

Comment: That doesn't help with what the wusten was about using the apt get comand

Comment: I was just trying to offer something that will work, cause I don't think what you want will.  Only other thing I can suggest is looking up how to make your own repository, but I think you will need to setup and import keys to get out working... Now that I think of it, it may be possible. Looking into it